# Как в Material UI разместить элементы на 1 линии?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу сделать форму. Добавил текстовый `input` и кнопку:

[image: скриншот].

Мне нужно,чтобы кнопка была на линии с инпутом, а не под ним. С React'ом начал работать недавно как и с Material UI,поэтому всего не знаю. 
Как можно выровнять эти элементы?

Первая мысль, которая меня посетила-влезть в дебри Material UI css файла и там поправить что-нибудь,но я думаю это глупо и предполагаю,что в библиотеке должны быть для этого нужные теги..код поля и кнопки приведен ниже:

```
const ButtonNew = () => (
  <div>
    <FlatButton label="New" />
  </div>
);

const EquipmentForm = () => (
  <div>

    <TextField
      hintText="Enter the Text"
      floatingLabelText="Equipment"
    />
    <ButtonNew/>
  </div>
);

export default EquipmentForm;
```

Comment: див - это блочный элемент - он растягивается во всех ширине родителя

Comment: вы правы, бахнул кнопке <span>вместо div-а и выровнялись.спасибо.вы не могли бы скопировать комментарий в ответ,чтобы я его отметил как правильный?

Comment: если вы сами нашли причину проблемы и решение - можете добавить свой ответ с описанием почему была ошибка и как решилась

Comment: Добавьте к оборачивающему div стили "display:flex;align-items:center" - должно помочь.